# Oracle avg in group by not sorting properly

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

We are receiving incorrect result ordering when using an order by on an aggregate function in a group by clause on Oracle 12.2. After playing around with it we have found that the query only works when it is phrased in certain ways (see below).

So here are our questions:

1) Why is ordering by avg acting finicky? Are the queries acting as expected based on some documented logic / limitation? Does it have something to do with the underlying data type being number(16) without decimal places?

2) Why does using an alias in query 4 make it work while query 3 does not work?

3) Why do the queries work better when ordering by ascending duration? It's not shown below but query 2 works when asc even though it does not work desc. Query 1 does not work with asc.

In the below examples note that duration is a number(16).

#### Query 1: Avg function order by function

```
select
    name,
    avg(duration)
from table1
join table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
where duration is not null
group by name
order by avg(duration) desc

-- Query 1 result (wrong)
(some name) 1224417.83471074
(some name) 33568438.1548673
(some name) 3928150.12809406
(some name) 1434939.13464658
(some name) 269338.574638521
```

#### Query 2: Avg function order by alias

```
-- Query 2: order by avg alias
select
    name,
    avg(duration) avg
from table1
join table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
where duration is not null
group by name
order by avg desc

-- Query 2 result (wrong)
-- See query 1 result

-- Note: For some reason this query works correctly when ordered asc
```

#### Query 3: Avg function with cast order by function

```
select
    name,
    to_number(avg(duration))
from table1
join table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
where duration is not null
group by name
order by to_number(avg(duration)) desc

-- Query 3 result (wrong)
-- See query 1 result
```

#### Query 4: Avg function with cast order by alias

```
select
    name,
    to_number(avg(duration)) avg
from table1
join table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
where duration is not null
group by name
order by avg desc

-- Query 4 results (correct)
(some name) 562654936
(some name) 498804314
(some name) 263681023
(some name) 245531731
(some name) 188103278
-- the values with decimals show up later in the right order
```

#### Query 5 & 6: Avg function with/without cast with ordering in an external query

```
select * from (
    select
        name,
        to_number(avg(duration)) avg -- works without to_number as well
    from table1
    join table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
    where duration is not null
    group by name
) order by avg desc

-- Query 5 & 6 results (correct)
-- See query 4 results
```

Comment: Your incorrect results are simply wrong (assuming the queries are accurate).  This would appear to be a bug in the version of Oracle that you are using.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, too. Provided, only one of the tables has a column called `duration` and there is no column called `avg` in the two tables

Comment: Take a look at the execution plans for each query, that may show you a transformation that the Optimizer performs that may or may not be logically wrong. In any case - can you post a minimal sample of data (your two tables, with as few columns as rows as possible, while still being able to recreate the wrong behavior you are reporting)?

Comment: It is indeed a bug. It shows up when the optimizer decides to use VW_GBC_5. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have traced this down to what we believe is a bug in the Oracle optimizer. It happens when the optimizer chooses to use a view called VW_GBC_5. Observe the explain plans below:

**With Issue**

```
-- This produces incorrect result set ordering
select 
    /*+ qb_name(m) place_group_by(@m) */ 
    name,
    avg(duration)
from table1
join table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
where duration is not null
group by name
order by avg(duration) desc;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                | 35540 |  3366K|       |  9433   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY         |                | 35540 |  3366K|  3800K|  9433   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY        |                | 35540 |  3366K|  3800K|  9433   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN           |                | 35540 |  3366K|       |  7852   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     VIEW               | VW_GBC_5       | 35540 |  1145K|       |  7510   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      HASH GROUP BY     |                | 35540 |   416K|       |  7510   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE1         |  1225K|    14M|       |  7461   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TABLE2         | 38955 |  2434K|       |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Without Issue**

```
-- This produces correct result set ordering
select 
    /*+ qb_name(m) no_place_group_by(@m) */ 
    name,
    avg(duration)
from table1
join table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
where duration is not null
group by name
order by avg(duration) desc;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                | 38412 |  2850K|       | 25624   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY       |                | 38412 |  2850K|    98M| 25624   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY      |                | 38412 |  2850K|    98M| 25624   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN         |                |  1225K|    88M|  2896K|  9345   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE2         | 38955 |  2434K|       |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE1         |  1225K|    14M|       |  7461   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Workarounds**

1. Rewrite query (see original question)
2. Disable _simple_view_merging

   alter session set "_simple_view_merging"=false;
3. Switch to a different optimizer version

   alter session set optimizer_features_enable='12.1.0.2';
4. Use the no_place_group_by optimizer hint

Answer (score 1):

I guess for correct output results you need to have the aggregation done already but here what happens is the aggregation when done after grouping again in order by you are having aggregation so this again starts aggregation on top of the aggregation already done even though its a alias using an outer query is most efficient to first finalize the output after aggregation then have the order by in the outer query like `select col1,col2 from (select col,agg(..) from table group by col) order by col2` this will limit to only ordering the received output not again aggregating and ordering.

Comment: A smart RDBMs will calculate an aggregate only once.